# The order of an element in a subgroup and in the parent group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$, and $h \in H$. 
What is the relation of the order of $h$ in $H$ and the order of $h$ in $G$?

I guess the answer is "the same". Let us denote by $h$ the order of $h$. Then

$(1)$ $|h|=m$ in $H$ $\iff$ $|h|=m$ in $G$.

$(2)$ $|h|=+\infty$ in $H$ $\iff$ $|h|=+\infty$ in $G$.

Because if we denote by  $\langle h \rangle$ the cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by $h$, then $\langle h \rangle \le H \le G$.
Moreover, we know $|h|=|\langle h \rangle|$.

What do you think?

Comment: It is indeed the same due to the fact that $\forall r, h^r \in H \subset G$

Comment: So the same as what I was proposing?

Comment: Yes! $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Indeed, for subgroups are *closed* under the group operation of the super-group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is exactly the same: a subgroup is namely characterized by the fact that it *inherits* the group structure from its parent group. With quotient groups this is different: an element could have infinite order in the parent group, while it has finite order in the quotient.

Comment: Can you give me an example of your second statement?

Comment: Take for example the element $2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. This has infinite order in $\mathbb{Z}$, but in the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z}$ it has order $3$. The other way around: if an element has infinite order in a quotient, then it must have infinite order in the parent group. Try to show that yourself!

Comment: Let $G$ be a group, $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Assume $a = g + H \in G/H$ has infinite order. Suppose to the contrary that the order of $a$ in $G$ is finite. Then there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that $a^m=e \in H$. Thus $g^m \in H$, which means the order $a$ in $G/H$ is finite giving a contradiction. How does this proof look?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the only remark: write $a=gH$, rather than the additive notation, the group does not have to be abelian. Well done!